# Why can't conversion to non-scalar types be performed if a suitable assignment operator exists?

Tags: c++

```
struct Foo {
    int val;
    Foo() : val(-1) {}
    explicit Foo(int val_) : val(val_) {}
    Foo& operator=(int val_) { val = val_; return *this; } 
    operator int () const { return val; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo = 1; // error
    Foo foo2;
    foo2 = 2; // works fine
    return 0;
}

error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Foo' requested
     Foo foo = 1;
```

The code should be self-explanatory.  I would like to understand why the direct assignment is illegal when a suitable assignment operator has been defined.

Comment: Look for the keyword `explicit` in your code.  You are asking why a `Foo` can not be **implicitly** constructed from an `int`.

Comment: [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `foo2 = 2;`, `Foo foo = 1;` is not assignment, but [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). Only constructors would be considered (to construct `foo`). The appropriate constructor `Foo::Foo(int)` is marked as [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) then can't be used in [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) like `Foo foo = 1;`.

If you make `Foo::Foo(int)` non-explicit then the code would work; [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (which considers `explicit` constructor) like `Foo foo(1);` works too.

Comment: I understand the error message.  I'm hoping to get more insight as to *why* this is the case.  Put another way, what would go wrong if the C++ language (and compilers) supported this code?  ...or maybe what I really am asking for is implicit construction.

Comment: @MarkB This is syntax. You're using initialization syntax; why are you hoping assignment should be performed?

Comment: @MarkB when you go out of your way to opt-out of allowing implicit conversions, it _is_ supporting your code by not compiling.  If you want implicit conversions enabled, don't mark it `explicit`, BUT implicit conversions are a common source of errors so don't be too quick to embrace them.  I prefer `explicit` constructors most of the time.